# How to compare CI_COMMIT_REF in Gitlab to list of value?

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci

I want to run a set a job in Gitlab only when the branch is not equal to develop, test or master. This is what codes look like:

```
Test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF == 'develop' || $CI_COMMIT_REF == 'test' || $CI_COMMIT_REF == 'master'
      when: never
  script:
    - echo "Test!"
```

I'm wondering if there's an efficient/shorter way to do this, like IN or CONTAINS keyword. Thanks!

Comment: I've used CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME here not CI_COMMIT_REF.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use regex for such a task - but than you have regex ;)

```yaml
Test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^(develop|master|test)$/
      when: never
  script:
    - echo "Test!"
```

that is the only way i can think, to make it `smaller`. But be aware smaller is not always easier to debug or read. This is a small regex, which makes it easy - but  regex can add another level of complexity which you maybe want to try to avoid.

For further reading i recommend https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules